# Different NSString results from URL download

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am parsing a string that I obtain from a website but get different results depending on how I download. 
This way it works:

```
NSString *tagiString = @"http://tagesanzeiger.ch";
NSURL *tagiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tagiString];
NSError *error;
NSString *text =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:tagiURL
                                             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                error:&error];
```

Te following way it does not work. I first download the data, feed it into the `NSMutableData *articleData` and then convert to a NSString with `initWithData:encoding:`

```
- (void)downloadWebsite
{
NSString *tagiString = @"http://tagesanzeiger.ch";
NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tagiString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteURL];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                             delegate:self
                                     startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [articleData appendData:data];
}

- (NSString *)data
{    
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:articleData
                                       encoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding];      
return text;
}
```

Seems like the resulting `NSString *text` content is not the same for both versions? Do I need to use a different string encoding? I have tried many without success.

Comment: what is different between the two resulting strings? Why don't you use NSASCIIStringEncoding too for the second method?

Comment: Even with NSASCIIStringEncoding in the second method it does not work. I have tried everything but am stuck.

Comment: Seems as if there is an issue with the last method. NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:articleData encoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding] returns an empty text string. Why is this?

Comment: try to log first to check whether the text is empty. Also check if articleData is empty.

Comment: @verbumdei: articleData is empty. I guess I need to check if the download is finished before I call the data method otherwise articleData is still void.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31065/discussion-between-verbumdei-and-pete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading to ensure the connection loading has finished where you can call your data method. Also try to use NSASCIIStringEncoding instead of 
NSSymbolStringEncoding.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.articleData
                                           encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //do whatever you need to do with the text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a different string encoding. You can try `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Here it's working for me. And `utf-8` is almost the most popular encoding way.