# How can I wait for a NSURLConnection delegate to finish before continuing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, delegates

I am trying to display my remotely configured settings in a modal view after the application launches. Everything is hooked up properly, but the view updates its labels before the `configs` object is updated from its `NSURLConnection` delegate methods.

I'm looking for a solution that will let the delegate methods finish before I try to update the view. I would rather not put the functionality in the delegate methods themselves so I can use the `MYRemoteConfig` in other situations.

I suspect the solution is obvious, but I've gone braindead from looking at this for too long.

---

In `viewDidAppear{}` in `MYSettingsViewController.m`

```
MYRemoteConfig* config = [[MYRemoteConfig alloc] init];
[configs updateSettings];  // I need these delegate methods to be done 
                           // before the next line
self.customerLabel.text = configs.customer;   // Updates with empty box
self.courseLabel.text = configs.course;
```

-

`updateSettings{}` in `MYRemoteConfig.m`

```
// code that gets uuid and sets up post request //

NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request 
                                                            delegate:self];
[connection start]; 
NSLog(@"Connection should have started.");
```

then in `connectionDidFinishLoading{}`: (after appending data to local var)

```
// pull JSON objects into dictionary
[self updateProfile:settingsDictionary; 
NSLog(@"%@", settingsDictionary);  //works
```

`updateProfile{}`:

```
// code that sets config attributes in singleton object //

self.customer = [settings objectForKey:@"Customer"];   //  I need this data
self.course = [settings objectForKey:@"Course"];       // in my view controller
```

Comment: This has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880686/different-nsstring-results-from-url-download

Comment: Setup notifications maybe? ;-) NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Or a delegate to your `MYRemoteConfig` class.

Comment: @Sam Budda - The answer to the question you provided is "Use the delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading`" As you can see, I already have implemented this. That link is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make MYSettingsViewController the delegate of MYRemoteConfig controller, create a delegate protocol in MYRemoteConfig, and call the method you create in that protocol in the connectionDidFinishLoading method. The implementation of that method in MYSettingsViewController would then update the customer and course labels.

Comment: Since `connectionDidFinishLoading` will be called by multiple objects, should I make MYRemoteConfig have a property like `calledFromMYSVC` that i set through an initializer like `initFromMYSVC`? Is that the best way to identify who is calling the function? Because the goal of this is to have MYRemoteConfig update the labels, but also be reusable for other classes.

Comment: @user I don't think you need to do anything like that. Any class that calls this will create its own instance of MYRemoteConfig, and would set itself as the delegate, so there is no need to have a property to keep track of who the delegate is.